# Adding existing kubernetes to gitlab throwing me error

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I have followed these [steps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_remove_clusters.html) to add my Kubernetes cluster to GitLab. Its added successfully. But while installing applications throwing error "Your cluster API is unreachable. Please ensure your API URL is correct."

Please suggest.

Comment: Is your cluster public or private ? Is it on  GKE or EKS ?
Also is access to master enabled ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla    Cluster is private, cluster is in on-premisis AWS instances. Access to master from wrkers; All traffice allowed from workers to master & 0.0.0.0/32 to master is allowed.

Comment: Where is gitlab running? AWS? Same VPC? Cloud?

Comment: not sure in which VPC gitlab server in . But gitlab runner is running on my master machine . And I allowed traffic from gitlab server to master machine.

 does gitlab server  should be in same VPC to make it possible ...?